# How to prevent from editing one part of localStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I got an example code from  [JasonWatMore][1] which is role based authorization
I tried to do it myself and it works fine but I found one big problem.

**I want to prohibit interference with the user roles**

Now in `authentication.service.t`s I got

```
   login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }
```

Where all data from backend is located in localSotrage which looks like

```
{id: 1, username: "admin", firstName: "Admin", lastName: "User", role: "User",…}
firstName: "Admin"
id: 1
lastName: "User"
role: "User"
token: "fake-jwt-token.Admin"
username: "admin"
```

and now when I opening developer tools I can edit role from User to Admin and I got all access to admin pages.

Is there any way to secure this role parametr?

And there is guard

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            // check if route is restricted by role
            if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1) {
                // role not authorised so redirect to home page
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                return false;
            }

            // authorised so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

How should I secure localStorage?
I also want to secure elements on page for example 
if Admin then show  else not ( I know how to do it but there is a problem because everyone can edit localStorage)
So I don't want to only secure routes

Comment: You cannot secure localStorage.  It is stored on the users browser, and is within their full control.

Comment: For localStorage the same security principles as for cookies apply: Don't store information in it which the user is not allowed to change!

Comment: Usually the roles aren't stored in the local/session storage. If you want to dynamically verify the roles, retrieve the token from the storage and extract the roles from it. Try not to store any sensitive information in the browser storage.

Comment: Storing the roles there is fine, just need to verify it on the server before you do the actions. So user can give them access, but on the server if they request that data, you can error out.

Comment: so I should every time veryify on the server side before access? On every component?

Comment: @MarcinDomorozki yes of course. Imagine on Facebook sometimes you need a password but sometimes not lol. Usually in a nodejs context you have a middleware doing checks on every request on a specific route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User service variables for storing that kind of data. But still if you only want to use localstorage, encrypt the data using bcrypt or something before storing. and decrypt it after getting it from localstorage.

Comment: But the logic will be visible so not rocket science to do the encryption/decryption

Comment: everything is visible on client side. if your user is so smart that he can see your bundle and code. You should never store confidential information on client side. have a token or something to get such data always from server. But even in that case if its unencrypted, user can see network tab right? If a user have access to information and your system ofcourse he can see all the data. You can only protect a door by locking it from people who don't have key by putting a unbreakable good quality lock. if somebody have key, what is the purpose of that lock, right?

Comment: I don't think it's the right solution in OP's case but I've used this technique to encrypt cached data on devices in the past with success. In my case we prompted the user for their password and derived the decryption key from this when logging in offline

Comment: Hmm I am sending data after login from my server like res.status(200).send({
          id: user.id,
          username: user.username,
          email: user.email,
          roles: authorities,
          accessToken: token
        });

Where can I store it on my client side? To prevent from editing?

Comment: inside a @Injectable() service property. but it will be lost on refresh. but if your user can read code and can put breakpoints in dev tools. he will be able to edit it.

Comment: hmm so what is best way to make roles in angular and make role based access to elements like buttons? For example admin can delete something but moderator no

Comment: create a subject in service. have its observable instance. Subscribe to that instance anywhere you want roles. Push your userrole object inside subject. That way whenever you will change userrole object in subject. Each subscribe will get new roles. The only thing is you will be needed to fetch roles again on refresh.

Comment: Can I do something like this?
this.userService.isAdmin().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.content = data;
        console.log('content: '+this.content);
      },
      err => {
        this.content = JSON.parse(err.error).message;
      }
    );

Comment: Now I can show user Role in localStorage but if any "smart" user want to edit it he can ...but it doesn't works for elements :)